# How to do formatting and trimming in polars dataframe?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a data frame with about 100 columns with a type of pl.Utf8, I would like to do trim/proper/title of each column at one go.

```
df_.with_columns(pl.all().str.strip_chars())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct:

```py
In [58]: df = pl.DataFrame({'a': ['1 ', '2 ', '3'], 'b': ['foo ', 'bar ', 'ignoring ']})

In [59]: df = df.with_columns(pl.all().str.strip_chars())

In [60]: df
Out[60]:
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬──────────┐
│ a   ┆ b        │
│ --- ┆ ---      │
│ str ┆ str      │
╞═════╪══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ foo      │
│ 2   ┆ bar      │
│ 3   ┆ ignoring │
└─────┴──────────┘

In [61]: df['a'][0]
Out[61]: '1'
```

If it doesn't work as expected, you might be on an old Polars version, could you update please?

Comment: Yes,its correct, i have older version of polars 0.18. in 0.19.XX it works.